# Rotation and move to relative center in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix-multiplication

I have a simple model which I want to rotate 360° and move in the new facing direction. My problem is when I translate the model because it rotates in (0,0,0) rather than in its own center. This is my code:

```
void Car::move(void){
    if (car_direction > TWO_PI) 
        car_direction -= TWO_PI;
    else
        car_direction += TWO_PI;

    car_x_pos = sin(car_direction)*incMov;
    car_z_pos = cos(car_direction)*incMov;

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(car_x_pos, car_y_pos, car_z_pos);
        glRotatef(RAD_TO_DEG * car_direction, 0, 1, 0);
        drawCar();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

****EDIT**

I found the problem, I was calculating wrong the x and z the correct code is:

```
void Car::move(void){
if (car_direction > TWO_PI) 
    car_direction -= TWO_PI;
else
    car_direction += TWO_PI;

car_z_pos += incMov * cos(car_direction); //correct calculation
car_x_pos += incMov * sin(car_direction); //correct calculation


glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(car_x_pos, car_y_pos, car_z_pos);
    glRotatef(RAD_TO_DEG * car_direction, 0, 1, 0);
    drawCar();
glPopMatrix();
```

}

Now the car can rotate and move without any problems.

Comment: A 360 degree rotation is a no-op.  Just move in your current direction.

Comment: Yeah, don't you mean 90 or 180 degrees?

Comment: I mean that the car/hover can rotate in his center 360° and then move to the new direction, but the problem is when I translate it then the center is no his center is (0,0,0) o want to rotate always in his center

Comment: @fmarin Then translate it to the origin, perform the rotation there and translate it back...

Comment: @Bart That's what I always did when I worked on OpenGL projects. Translate, rotate, translate back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have your order backwards.  Try calling Rotate first, then Translate.